# Select from different tables -> users and billing

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a value from differente tables, I have 2 tables that are `users` and `billing`, and I want to select the billings of `@identifier` (variable) and then select the name of the sender of the bill.

I want to "join" two selects like:

```
SELECT *
FROM billing
WHERE identifier = @identifier
```

(`@indentifier` is a local variable) and, at the same time:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE identifier = billing.sender
```

Comment: You're looking for `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`). I suggest reading some tutorials on how to use those and what the differences are between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM billing b
JOIN users u ON u.identifier = billing.sender
WHERE b.identifier = @identifier
```